# what is wrong here

Tags: c++

```
   unsigned __int8 result[]= new unsigned __int8[sizeof(username) * 4];
```

IntelliSense: initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object

Comment: Do you have a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) you're learning from?

Comment: @GMan nope, plus what if i want to return result how can i do that!?

Comment: Well before you can program in C++ you need to learn C++, so do pick up one of those books.

Answer (score 1):

The types are not the same; you cannot initialize an array with a pointer.

`new unsigned __int8[sizeof(username) * 4];` returns a `unsigned __int8*`, not `unsigned __int8[]`

change your code to

```
unsigned __int8* result = new unsigned __int8[sizeof(username) * 4];
```

Comment: what if i want to return result how can i do that!?

Comment: @Kevin  i mean if result is = 5; i want to return 5 , coz i cant return reslut while it's pointing for something else , i need to get it's value from the memory or something

Comment: @TQCopier Do you mean the value pointed by `result`? In that case you cold do this: `return *result;` which returns the value pointed by `result`.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned __int8 *result = new unsigned __int8[sizeof(username) * 4];
```

Answer (score 0):

new returns a pointer, not an array. You should declare

```
unsigned __int8* result = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

here, result is an array of __int8, so you can't assign one value into the entire array.  You actually want:

```
unsigned __int8* p_result = new unsigned __int8[sizeof username * 4];
```